# Access php database server cpanel

Tags: mysql, database

I can't connect to my `MySQL` database which is held by a hosting provider.

I've set up accounts correctly in `cPanel` so I can connect to database when I run my `php` code from `phpadmin` server.

But now I want to access it from a database tool on Mac rather than `phpmyadmin`. I've added my `IP` (both `IP` and `DNS` name..) to "Remote Database Access Hosts" in `cPanel`.
I've tried to connect both from `PHP` and directly. I always get:

```
MySQL Said: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (4)

Use the following configuration settings for connecting to your database:
```

I have tried this:

1. Host name = (use the server IP address)
2. Database name =(cpanelUsername_databaseName)
3. Database username = (cpanelUsername_databaseUsername)
4. Database password = (the password you entered for that database user)
5. MySQL Connection Port = 3306

Comment: Could be that the hosting provider does not allow you accessing your database from an other ip adress

Comment: Your adding the IP of your computer right? Not the IP of your server.

Comment: not sure if this was the case, but if it was why would they provide a way to whitelist an ip ?

Comment: I am adding the ip i foind on whatmyip.com

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to phpMyAdmin you might be able to edit the user account created by cpanel.
In the "Users" tab, go to "Edit privileges" on the user you want to use from remote. Then there should be a popup where you can scroll down and find a section called "Login Information".

The value set for "Host" is "localhost" by default, set this to "%" (without quotes) for that user to be used from every remote IP address.

Comment: This could leave CodeMonkey without a way to access the database -- since 'localhost' is special to MySQL and % doesn't include localhost, it's possible that could remove the only means by which to access the database. Better to create a new user, but as noted elsewhere that's probably not going to be allowed by the hosting provider due to security concerns.